# Free C / C++ static analysis tool to detect integral promotion, overflow / truncation

Tags: c++, c

For C / C++ projects (especially large ones), detecting all these errors can be very hard.

More info can be found [here](http://c-faq.com/expr/intoverflow1.html).

PC-Lint / FlexeLint software from Gimpel Software LLC can do this. Tested with their web checker. It detects the following warning:
main.c(13) : [Warning 647](http://www.gimpel.com/html/bugs/bug647.htm): Suspicious truncation

I have also tried with frama-c, splint and cppcheck without detecting it.

Which free tool can I use to detect this problem in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    int32_t a, b;
    int64_t result;

    a = INT32_MAX;
    b = 2;

    // Wrong
    result = a * b;
    printf("result    = %" PRId64 "\n", result);

    // Right
    result = (int64_t)a * b;
    printf("result    = %" PRId64 "\n", result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [AdLint](http://adlint.sourceforge.net/) available on SourceForge.

It is an open source, free, static code analyzer.  It should cover most of your requirements.

Comment: Does it put a warning on line 13 in this case?

Comment: Puts W0722 and W0578 on the line, not as clear and PC-Lint but it's good enough, thank you